# How to open word document with /m "Macro argument" from java/or command-line without to specifi winword.exe path

Tags: java, ms-word, runtime, exec

I want to do the next thing:

```
String[] cmd  = {"cmd","/c","c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.exe","/mOpenPage","c:\\Navodilo.doc"};            
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But, without to specify the winword.exe path but open the document with the macro...

I read that there exist Auto Open macro, is it possible to specify input arguments for Auto Open macro?

**SOLVED:**

```
String[] cmd  = {"cmd","/c","start","WINWORD.exe","/mOpenPage","c:\\Navodilo_za_uporabo_spletnega_servisa_wsEdp.doc"};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

It runs default winword.exe and open word document with specified Macro

Answer (score 1):

I see two options for you:

1. Read the path to winword.exe from the Registry. It is stored under

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\InstallRoot
   ```

   where `12.0` needs to be the correct Office version (Office 2007 = 12, Office 2003 = 11 etc).
2. Instead of using the /m switch you could also use an auto macro. How this is done is described here:

   > http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211659

Comment: Hm... yes, Auto macro. But it will be static. I want somehow to say in runtime to open that document on that page/bookmark or similar