# C# 2010 Word - How to create tables without an empty line between

Tags: c#, ms-word

Using C# 2010 I need to open a word 2010 template, search for a bookmark and insert a table there. Actually it should be a 'three-part-table': one row with two columns, after that multiple rows with five columns and finall three rows as single columns. And it should look as one table without paragraphs or empty lines between.

My experience with word automation is quite limited. I can find examples how to create a table at a bookmark - no problem so far - but how can I add a new table immediately after the one before...

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. You don't need multiple tables in order to have different columns; Word lets you have a single table where the first row has 2 columns, the next 3 rows have 5 columns, and the last 3 rows only have 1 column. (You didn't say how many rows you needed with five columns, so I just went with 3.)

```
//Be sure to add this reference:
//Project>Add Reference>.NET tab>Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

//open Word App
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application msWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

//make it visible or it'll stay running in the background
msWord.Visible = true;

//open a new document based on the Word template.
//You shouldn't open the template directly using msWord.Documents.Open(path) unless you want to edit the template itself.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = msWord.Documents.Add(@"c:\MyTemplate.dotx");

//find the bookmark
string bookmarkName = "BookmarkToFind";

if (wordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName))
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark bk = wordDoc.Bookmarks[bookmarkName];

    //set the document's range to immediately after the bookmark.
    //If you want to add the table *into* the bookmark, it needs to be done differently.
    //This page has a good explanation of the differences between adding to the bookmark's range vs adding after the bookmark's range.
    //http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/insert_text_at_or_in_bookmark.html
    //It's a little more hassle because you have to re-add the bookmark after inserting into it,
    //so inserting after the bookmark is usually fine less you're going to be inserting text programmatically at the same bookmark a second time.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = wordDoc.Range(bk.Range.End, bk.Range.End);

    //create a table with 8 rows and 5 columns into the range.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tbl = wordDoc.Tables.Add(rng, 8, 5);

    //set the table's borders.
    tbl.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
    tbl.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;

    //merge the cells in the first row down to 2 columns (Word's cells start at 1, not at 0).
    tbl.Cell(1, 1).Merge(tbl.Cell(1, 3));

    //distribute the columns evenly
    tbl.Rows[1].Select();
    msWord.Selection.Cells.DistributeWidth();

    //rows 2-5 already have 5 columns so don't touch them.

    //merge rows 6-8 into single-columns rows.
    for (int x = 6; x < 9; x++)
    {
        tbl.Cell(x,1).Merge(tbl.Cell(x,5));
    }

    //put the cursor in the table's first cell.
    rng=wordDoc.Range(tbl.Cell(1,1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(1,1).Range.Start);
    rng.Select();
```